# Removing/disabling backticks on variable in Active Record query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a "between" query on my database using the Query Class of CodeIgniter, however, when adding a variable to the where clause, it adds backticks to the variable.

```
$this->db->select(TABLE_DISCOUNTSCARRIER.'.discount')->select(TABLE_DISCOUNTSCARRIER.'.idCarrier')
$this->db->from(TABLE_DISCOUNTSCARRIER);
$this->db->join(TABLE_DISCOUNTS, TABLE_DISCOUNTSCARRIER.'.idDiscount='.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.idDiscount');
$this->db->where(TABLE_DISCOUNTSCARRIER.'.idCarrier', $carrier);
$this->db->where($data['from'].' BETWEEN '.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.from AND '.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.to');
$this->db->or_where($data['to'].' BETWEEN '.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.from AND '.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.to');
```

Which is being parsed into this (the last two lines)

```
SELECT 
    discountbycarrier.discount, 
    discountbycarrier.idCarrier 
FROM (discountbycarrier) 
JOIN discounts 
ON discountbycarrier.idDiscount=discounts.idDiscount 
WHERE `discountbycarrier`.`idCarrier` = '6' 
AND `5` BETWEEN discounts.from AND discounts.to 
OR `10` BETWEEN discounts.from AND discounts.to
```

Already tried setting the $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false; but it removes the backticks on the rest of the statements but not the variables. Already tried using the intval() of the variable but neither this works.
As you can see the variable $carrier is correctly being parsed as integer. 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your issue is the lack of back-ticks, specifically here `discounts.from`  not from having them the word `from` is reserved.

Comment: It doesn't have ticks because i just set the _protect_identifiers to false. If I enable it the rest of the query has back ticks, including the discounts from.

Comment: I use proper SQL and not their stupid query builder, besides shouldn't you be putting like `?` and then supplying the value or something.  Otherwise this is ripe for SQL injection ... just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
   discounts.from
```

to

```
  discounts.`from`
```

Or better (best practice) don't use reserved keywords for table columns, the word `FROM` is part of the query language, in other words.

Backticks are used to escape reserved keywords and spaces.

**UPDATE**

Something like this ( although I didn't look the documentation )

```
  $this->db->where('? BETWEEN '.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.from AND '.TABLE_DISCOUNTS.'.to', $data['from']);
```

Answer (score 0):

add this before the query

```
$this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
```

Comment: I posted that I used it and the backticks appeared anyways

Comment: oh sorry i didn't see that. Can you post your expected query string?